# Find the least number of points.

Tags: combinatorics

Let be given $n>4$ points in the plane and no three are colinear. Every point is connected to exactly three other points. If the point A is not connected to point B, then there is a point, let say point C, which is connected to A and B. Find the least value of $n$.

Comment: It can be done with six points.

Comment: To avoid having your Question placed on hold, you might add some context to your post:  What motivates the problem?  What have you done to try and solve it?

Comment: It is an abomination to label something like this "off-topic" instead of saying it's closed because of insufficient information (presumably on what the poster has done so far to try to solve the problem?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The first thing to notice is that $n$ must be even; why? It follows that $n\ge 6$, so you ought to try building an example with $n=6$; if you succeed, you’re done, and if you don’t the manner of failure may give you more insight into what such a graph must be like. I suggest that you start with a vertex $A$ that is connected to vertices $B,C$, and $D$, and add vertices $E$ and $F$ off to the side somewhere. Each of $E$ and $F$ must be connected to three vertices, and there really aren’t many different things to try.